# Странная проблема с mysql запросом

Tags: pdo, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT `news`.*, `user`.`name` FROM `news` JOIN `user` ON `news`.`author` = `user`.`id` ORDER by `news`.`id` DESC LIMIT :first, :pages

php:
$news = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `news`.*, `user`.`name` FROM `news` JOIN `user` 
ON `news`.`author` = `user`.`id` ORDER by `news`.`id` DESC LIMIT :first, :pages ");
$news->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':pages' => ONPAGE));
$allnews = $news->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Вардамп запроса:
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(130) "SELECT `news`.*, `user`.`name` FROM `news` JOIN `user` ON `news`.`author` = `user`.`id` ORDER by `news`.`id` DESC LIMIT '0', '10' " }
```

Он выбирает новости с базы данных. В first и pages инт значения, в запрос они тоже попадают, проверял вардампом, но получаемый массив почему-то пустой. Когда подставляю в запрос числа всё работает. Почему так?

Comment: Вы полностью напишите, как запрос выполняете, вы может объявили first и pages, но в запрос их не передаете?

Т.е. еще и PHP покажите. Можно даже с выводом, т.к. не известно, где вы цифры подставляете, может, в коде, а может, и в mysql-клиенте.

Comment: @BOPOH добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так... Вы лимит по строке сделать пытаетесь, а надо по числам.
Посмотрите примеры c PARAM_INT, либо обновите сервер, т.к. это вроде багом является (см. SO)